# How to signal EOF on a file the program opens

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, eof, lexical-analysis

How would I signal an EOF when reading in a file in C++? I'm writing a direct coded scanner, as a part of a compiler design, that reads in a file and splits it up into tokens for a language.

I am to read in the whole program, strip out the comments, and compress the whitespace. Then put the resulting program char by char into a buffer with max size of 1024 chars. So when we empty we will refill the buffer or what not.

To open the file I have this written:

```
// Open source file.
source_file.open (filename);
if (source_file.fail()) {
   // Failed to open source file.
   cerr << "Can't open source file " << *filename << endl;
   buffer_fatal_error();
```

To fill the buffer, I am wanting to use a while loop and iterate like

```
int i = 0;
// Iterate through the whole file
while(source_file.at(i) != EOF)
{
   // If not a tab or newline add to buffer
   if (source_file.at(i) != "\n" || source_file.at(i) != "\t")
   {
      bufferList.add(source_file.at(i));
   }
   i++;
}
```

Would there be a way to signal EOF like that for the file that I am opening?

This is more or less a general outline for what to do. I will need to figure out how to refill the buffer once I am empty or to use dual buffering. I also need to figure out how to strip out a comment which would begin with `#`. For instance `# This is a comment`. My scanner would see `#` and remove everything after that until it gets the the next newline char.

Comment: EOF mean you are just looking for a null value at the end of the file

Comment: Try using `std::vector<char>` for the buffer and `istream::read()` to read in the data into the buffer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews will `istream::read()` strip out whitespace?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews also we can only take in 1024 chars at a time so we will have to refill the buffer periodically. Not sure how to signal for that.

Comment: The `istream::read` does not strip whitespace.  You can do that when you parse the buffer.  Put the `istream::read` into a `while` expression.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Are you sure you've understood? Compilers don't read in entire files before doing any processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char c;
std::vector<char> buffer(1024);
while (source_file.get(c))
{
  if ((c != '\n') || (c != '\t'))
  {
     buffer.push_back(c);
  }
}
```

The standard method for reading data is to test for the result of the read operation in a `while` loop.

For block reading, you could do something like this:

```
char buffer[1024];
while (source_file.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer))
{
  // Process the buffer here
}
```

You should also use `std::istream::gcount()` to get the number of characters read from the file, as it could be less than the buffer size.

Comment: I understand the top portion of this answer. But does it make a difference to say `source_file.get(c)` as compared to `source_file.at(c)`, or are they the same? I guess I am just confused on what `read` does and how to use that to strip out comments and compress whitespace.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the `at()` method for [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream).